# Show that intersection property - $I(X,Y\cup Z, W)$ and $I(X,W\cup Z,Y)$ $\implies$ $I(X,Z,Y\cup W)$ - requires strict positive distribution

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, causality, independence, graphical-model

### Question

It is stated in *Probabilistic Reasoning In Intelligent Systems* by *Judea Pearl* that, intersection property of information relevance axioms -

> $I(X,Y\cup Z, W)$ and $I(X,W\cup Z,Y)$ $\implies$ $I(X,Z,Y\cup W)$

holds only for strictly positive probability distributions, i.e., $P(x,y,w,z)>0$  $\forall$  $x\ \epsilon \ X$, $y\ \epsilon \ Y$, $w\ \epsilon \ W$, $z\ \epsilon \ Z$.

However, I went through the steps (given below for reference) for proving this property and I could only find the requirement $P(y,w,z)>0$ (memberships same as above). **With $X$ not included, where is the strictly positive constraint coming from?**

### Proof

To prove $I\left(X,Z\cup Y,W\right)\ and\ I\left(X,Z\cup W,Y\right)\Rightarrow\ I(X,Z,Y\cup\ W)$
$I\left(X,Z\cup Y,W\right)$
$\Rightarrow\ P\left(x\middle|\ w,\left(y,z\right)\right)=P\left(x\middle|\ y,z\right)$...........$(i)$
$I\left(X,Z\cup W,Y\right)$
$\Rightarrow\ P\left(x\middle|\ y,\left(w,z\right)\right)=P\left(x\middle|\ w,z\right)$......$(ii)$
Therefore, from $(i)$ and $(ii)$ [both $(i)$ and $(ii)$ require that $P(y,z,w)>0$ always]
$P\left(x\middle|\ y,z\right)=P\left(x\middle|\ w,z\right)$
$\Rightarrow\ P\left(x\middle|\ y,z\right)P\left(w\middle|\ z\right)=P\left(x\middle|\ z,w\right)P\left(w\middle|\ z\right)$
$\Rightarrow\sum_{w}{P\left(x\middle|\ y,z\right)P\left(w\middle|\ z\right)}=\sum_{w}{P\left(x\middle|\ z,w\right)P\left(w\middle|\ z\right)}$
$\Rightarrow\ P\left(x\middle|\ y,z\right)=P\left(x\middle|\ z\right)$
$\Rightarrow\ I(X,Z,Y)$
$I\left(X,Z,Y\right)\ and\ I\left(X,Z\cup Y,W\right)\Rightarrow\ I(X,Z,Y\cup\ W)$  by contraction.